# track facebook logout

Tags: facebook, logout

Thanks in advance.

How can I track facebook logout, when user is not on my facebook application? I've offline_access permission from my app user.

I am developing a facebook app, in which I want to show to other my app user that which (my app) user is login on facebook at this particular time.

Answer (score 1):

You have no way of knowing what the user is up to when he's not in your application.

You have 2 options:

(1) Ask for the "user_online_presence" [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the user, then check what's his status using a fql like this:

```
SELECT uid, name, online_presence FROM user WHERE uid=me();
```

(Take a look at the result in the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20uid,%20name,%20online_presence%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me%28%29;))

(2) You can use the [Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) to connect the user to the xmpp, then you get presence messages for all of his online friends, and that can help you to maintain the online presence of a users friends.